# Calculate the % of each occurrence of a column value and group by an ID

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I looked into many examples but non was comprehensive enough for my case. I have the following data sample:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Teacher ID': [123456,789456,101112,131415],
                  'Q1':[3,2,4,3],
                  'Q2':[3,3,3,3],
                  'Q3':[3,2,3,3],})
```

| Teacher ID | Q1 | Q2 | Q3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123456 | 3 | 3 | 3 |
| 789456 | 2 | 3 | 3 |
| 123456 | 3 | 3 | 3 |
| 131415 | 4 | 3 | 3 |

I would like For each teacher ID to know the % of times he graded 1 or 2 or 3 or 4 or 5 for each of the columns above (Questions) and add each of these % to a new column in the dataframe. Note that Teacher ID can appear more than once in the column Teacher ID.

The output should look like:

| Teacher ID | %Q1 Graded 1 | %Q1 Graded 2 | %Q1 Graded 3 | %Q2 Graded 1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123456 | 0% | 0% | 50% | 0% |
| 789456 | 0% | 25% | 0% | 0% |
| 131415 | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% |

Comment: What is the expected result?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) for unpivot, then [`SeriesGroupBy.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.value_counts.html) for count values per `Teacher ID` and question in column `Q`, reshape by [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html), add all missing Grades (for each question 1 to 5) and last divide by length of original DataFrame:

```
#get all question by columns names with omit first (Teacher ID)
mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df.columns[1:], range(1, 6)])

df1 = (df.melt('Teacher ID', var_name='Q')
         .groupby(['Teacher ID','Q'])['value']
         .value_counts()
         .unstack([1,2], fill_value=0)
         .reindex(mux, axis=1, fill_value=0)
         .div(len(df))
         .mul(100)
         )
df1.columns = df1.columns.map(lambda x: f'%{x[0]} Graded {x[1]}')
```

Alternative solution with [`crosstab`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html):

```
mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df.columns[1:], range(1, 6)])

df1 = df.melt('Teacher ID', var_name='Q')

df1 = (pd.crosstab(df1['Teacher ID'], [df1['Q'], df1['value']])
         .reindex(mux, axis=1, fill_value=0)
         .div(len(df))
         .mul(100))
df1.columns = df1.columns.map(lambda x: f'%{x[0]} Graded {x[1]}')
```

---

```
print (df1)
            %Q1 Graded 1  %Q1 Graded 2  %Q1 Graded 3  %Q1 Graded 4  \
Teacher ID                                                           
123456               0.0           0.0          50.0           0.0   
131415               0.0           0.0           0.0          25.0   
789456               0.0          25.0           0.0           0.0   

            %Q1 Graded 5  %Q2 Graded 1  %Q2 Graded 2  %Q2 Graded 3  \
Teacher ID                                                           
123456               0.0           0.0           0.0          50.0   
131415               0.0           0.0           0.0          25.0   
789456               0.0           0.0           0.0          25.0   

            %Q2 Graded 4  %Q2 Graded 5  %Q3 Graded 1  %Q3 Graded 2  \
Teacher ID                                                           
123456               0.0           0.0           0.0           0.0   
131415               0.0           0.0           0.0           0.0   
789456               0.0           0.0           0.0          25.0   

            %Q3 Graded 3  %Q3 Graded 4  %Q3 Graded 5  
Teacher ID                                            
123456              50.0           0.0           0.0  
131415              25.0           0.0           0.0  
789456               0.0           0.0           0.0
```

For percentages:

```
mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df.columns[1:], range(1, 6)])

df1 = (df.melt('Teacher ID', var_name='Q')
         .groupby(['Teacher ID','Q'])['value']
         .value_counts()
         .unstack([1,2], fill_value=0)
         .reindex(mux, axis=1, fill_value=0)
         .div(len(df))
         .applymap("{:.2%}".format)
         )
df1.columns = df1.columns.map(lambda x: f'%{x[0]} Graded {x[1]}')
print (df1)
           %Q1 Graded 1 %Q1 Graded 2 %Q1 Graded 3 %Q1 Graded 4 %Q1 Graded 5  \
Teacher ID                                                                    
123456            0.00%        0.00%       50.00%        0.00%        0.00%   
131415            0.00%        0.00%        0.00%       25.00%        0.00%   
789456            0.00%       25.00%        0.00%        0.00%        0.00%   

           %Q2 Graded 1 %Q2 Graded 2 %Q2 Graded 3 %Q2 Graded 4 %Q2 Graded 5  \
Teacher ID                                                                    
123456            0.00%        0.00%       50.00%        0.00%        0.00%   
131415            0.00%        0.00%       25.00%        0.00%        0.00%   
789456            0.00%        0.00%       25.00%        0.00%        0.00%   

           %Q3 Graded 1 %Q3 Graded 2 %Q3 Graded 3 %Q3 Graded 4 %Q3 Graded 5  
Teacher ID                                                                   
123456            0.00%        0.00%       50.00%        0.00%        0.00%  
131415            0.00%        0.00%       25.00%        0.00%        0.00%  
789456            0.00%       25.00%        0.00%        0.00%        0.00
```

Comment: can you please explain the var_name='Q' as well as the unstack[1,2]?

Comment: @Mona - it is variable name from [`DataFrame.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) generated from columns names, so it means `Q` like questions. `unstack(1,2)` means use second and third level of MultiIndex for convert to columns.